# firebase.on method throws not a function error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the error I'm getting
`Uncaught TypeError: _config_fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.on is not a function`

My other firebase functions, usually firebase auth are executing fine (not in this file). Am I importing it wrong or something?
Here is how I'm calling it:

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-unused-state */
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import fbase from '../config/fire';
import Entry from './leaderboard_entry';

class Leaderboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: Map(),
    };
  }

  initialize() {
    fbase.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const newUserState = snapshot.val();
      this.setState({ users: Map(newUserState) });
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

and here's config if you need it

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  databaseURL:
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId:
  appId: 
};

const fbase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fbase;
```

Details redacted.

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, you are trying to execute [on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) which is for [References](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) incorrectly on a firebase [App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App). Update your code to access the [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database) and get a reference to the path of your data, then you can hook into on value:

```
fbase.database().ref('/some-path').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const newUserState = snapshot.val();
  this.setState({ users: Map(newUserState) });
}, (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Also you would need to do static imports for any modules you are using:

```
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I need to add import statements in my config and specify database on my fbase calls right?

Comment: Yes, import the modules you are using as static imports and call database() along with a ref to a path of data that exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need import firebase/firestore package.

Your code should be as below.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  databaseURL:
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId:
  appId: 
};

const fbase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fbase;
```